# Not able to access admin console after Installing and activating a plugin

Tags: fatal-error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method wpdb::check_safe_collation() in /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2668 Stack trace: #0 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(237): wpdb->get_results(‘SELECT option_n…’) #1 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1717): wp_load_alloptions() #2 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(664): is_blog_installed() #3 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed() #4 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-config.php(94): require_once(‘/home/xyz…’) #5 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once(‘/home/xyz…’) #6 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once(‘/home/xyz…’) #7 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once(‘/home/xyz…’) #8 {main} thrown in /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2668

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method wpdb::check_safe_collation() in /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2668 Stack trace: #0 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(237): wpdb->get_results(‘SELECT option_n…’) #1 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/option.php(116): wp_load_alloptions() #2 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(69): get_option(‘WPLANG’) #3 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(137): get_locale() #4 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php(828): determine_locale() #5 /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(46): load_default_textdomain() #6 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #7 {main} thrown in /home/xyzcom/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2668
```

Getting above error after installing and activating shortcoder plugin. This happens when I try to access wp-admin page. Tried removing the plugin logging in via FTP and still it is not working. Can someone please help with the error?

Comment: [check_safe_collation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/check_safe_collation/) was added in WordPress 4.2. Are you running an older version?

Comment: However I don't see the plugin in the call stack either. Can you check if something e.g. that plugin has set up an alternate DB class at /wp-content/db.php? If it has, try removing or renaming that.